# Can Bitcoin Core be made to display/enter amounts in USD or other fiat currencies?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Every time I need to make Bitcoin payments, I have to switch many times between Bitcoin Core and my separate Bitcoin currency converter. For example, to see how much that transaction fee is in USD.

It would be very useful if it could be made to display a fiat currency instead.

Since this requires reliance on a third-party service, I understand why this is not built in.

However, can't I enter in the configuration file something like:

```
currency_converter_url = 'http://127.0.0.1/btcconverter/'
```

And then Bitcoin Core could make requests such as:

```
http://127.0.0.1/btcconverter/?satoshis=123456&to_currency_code=USD
```

In order for my own script to output how much that many satoshis are in USD currently, so that it can display it to me.

Is this possible? It would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible in Bitcoin Core. You will have to use a third party wallet software such as Electrum if you want this functionality.

There also isn't any standardized format for exchange rate APIs, so you will be limited to the exchanges that are already built into the wallet you select.

Comment: You missed the part where I said it was my own custom script. I can control exactly what is outputted to it, but apparently Bitcoin Core doesn't have this ability, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I mean... no, Bitcoin Core doesn't come with the feature to interface with your own custom script, considering that would be a feature that's only useful to you.

Comment: Only useful to me? Are you serious? This is the most useful non-crucial feature imaginable.

Comment: There's an argument to be made for implementing with existing major exchange price APIs (but they'd rather not build third party API connections into Bitcoin Core)... however I can't imagine what the argument is for something that works only for your personal custom script.

Comment: What is your problem? The point of mentioning my custom script is that it can be ADOPTED to whatever Bitcoin Core expects/wants. Not that Bitcoin Core has to do it exactly like I have come up with it. Jeez.

Comment: @ieatpizza I don't really understand what you're getting at here. I've added my own answer that hopefully clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to say about this. Bitcoin Core doesn't support this, presumably because nobody found it interesting enough to work on. It is open source software, without any governing body that sets the project's priorities. If you want it, you're free to work on it yourself, or convince someone else to do so.

I don't think there is anything fundamentally wrong with the idea. Bitcoin Core has a policy of not relying on any centralized services, but that doesn't preclude the ability to let users configure a script or URI to fetch exchange rate information from.